# not getting success when using retryWhen

Tags: rx-java, rx-java3

I want to receive success after successful retry. Here's my minimal working example:

```
        var i = 0

        Observable.just(i)
            .flatMapSingle {
                println(i)
                i++
                when {
                    it < 3 -> Single.error(Exception())
                    else -> Single.just(it)
                }
            }
            .retryWhen { errorObservable -> errorObservable
                .take(4)
            }
            .subscribe { println("subscribe $i") }
```

this will subscribe and print `0, subscribe 1`. If I uncomment commented lines, I'll get only `0, 1, 2, 3`
How do I get successful value in subscribe in given example?

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you want to solve? It is not clear, what you want to achieve.